# How to sum amounts according their ID-s

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with 2 tables in SQL Server 2008 Express.

My problem is the following: I would like to create a trigger to sum some values in first table and copy the sum into second one.

For example the first table (Head) has 5 columns :

```
  ID    Transaction    Acount    Date        Total_sum

   1    some text      acount1   2014.04.15   300
   2    some text      acount2   2014.04.15   500
   3    some text      acount1   2014.04.15   200
```

And the second table Transaction:

HeadID    Amount    Remarks

```
1       100        test1
1       200        test2
2       500        test3
3       100        test3
3       100        test4
```

So finally I would like to sum the values in Transaction if they have the same HeadID and copy the result into the Head table. (Total_sum column).Maybe first Could I find the last ID in the 'Head' table and group HeadID-s in the 'Transaction' table and sum the values

Please help me!

Comment: Update head a set total_sum=(select sum(t.total) from transaction t group by id) where t.id=a.id

Answer (score 0):

You can UPDATE table using JOIN

```
UPDATE h
SET h.Total_sum = t.sumTotal
FROM Head h
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT HeadID,SUM(Amount) as sumTotal
FROM [Transaction]
GROUP BY HeadID
) t
ON h.ID=t.HeadID
```

Comment: note, this will not set sum's to 0 if all transaction records are removed for a head.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the following:

```
create trigger TransactionInsertUpdateDelete
on Transaction
for insert, update, delete
as
begin
    update H
    set Total_sum = 
        -- set the total sum to the sum of all records for this head id in transaction
        (select sum(Amount) 
        from Transaction as T
        where T.HeadID = H.HeadID
        )
    from Head as H
    join -- join on the inserted and deleted tables to find out which HeadID's were affected.
        (select HeadID
        from inserted
        union
        select HeadID
        from deleted
        ) as C
        on C.HeadID = H.HeadID
end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can try like this ?

```
UPDATE Head h
SET h.Total_sum=(SELECT SUM(t.Amount) FROM Transaction t
               Where t.HeadID = t.HeadID
               GROUP BY t.HeadID)
WHERE h.ID= t.HeadID
```

Answer (score 0):

you could achive it without using join:

```
UPDATE tansaction_table
   SET Total_sum = (SELECT SUM(t2.Amount) 
                   FROM head_table t2 
                  WHERE t2.HeadID = ID)
```